# Installing of Angular is not successful. No errors shown

Tags: node.js, angular

If you look a the picture I made sure I had npm and node and then tried to install Angular CLI and it does not give me an error or anything.  I am not sure what I have done.  This laptop did crash a while back and I reloaded it not sure if that would contribute to this issue.

I even updated npm and node to the latest to see if that would fix the issue.  I am on Windows 10 Home edition.  The angular CLI seems to be working on my home desktop.  How can I get this working again even if I uninstall something to get it working correctly.

[image: Here are the steps I took]

[image]

I thought it was NPM but somehow I have the loglevel set to silent.

[image: Next Issue but with errors.]

Comment: check https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Maybe it is an NPM issue. maybe not Angular  Just did this.  I have been doing so much I might have broke something.

C:\code\angular>npm i -g @angular/cli

C:\code\angular>npm i express

C:\code\angular>npm i express -g

C:\code\angular>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally uninstalled NODE completely and found the extra folders left over and reinstalled and that has fixed my issue.  Nothing to do with Angular.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it globally,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Yeah I did that too... just  missed it in the photo but did it again to show it is not showing an error or running anything.

Answer (score 1):

Give an uninstall a try.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

In the screenshot you posted, there is this line

```
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
```

Maybe you should reinstall node also.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
npm install angular-cli
```

Comment: That is a old version of the cli